# Why most of the data structures in generic collections use array despite of Large Object Heap fragmentation?

Tags: c#, coreclr

I could see that [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs) and [CoreFx](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs) implicitly use array for most of the generic collections. what is the main driving factor to go with arrays and how it handles any side effects of LOH fragmentation.

Comment: Using arrays by itself doesn't cause LOH fragmentation. It's careless code that causes fragmentation. When you *know* you're going to insert a lot of items, set the capacity.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If the arrays are larger than 85K bytes (note: not 85K *elements*), they *will* go on the LOH, in which case they *could* cause fragmentation of the LOH, depending on the sequence of allocations and deallocations. Arrays do not have a capacity (Lists do).

Comment: @MatthewWatson oh, good, I leave that one to you :P You can explain the read vs insert benefit, capacity, etc better than me

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't need to explain that, I just wanted to point out that using arrays by themselves *can* cause LOH fragmentation.

Comment: What do you think they should use as an alternative?

Comment: .NET collection types (except LinkedList) emphasize speed first.  The memory sub-system in modern machines strongly favor arrays, it optimizes for sequential memory access in their cache design.  Still fretting over LOH fragmentation no longer makes sense, 64-bit operating systems are ubiquitous today.

Comment: @HansPassant CPUs and their SIMD operations like arrays too, eg zeroing 16 or 32 bytes in a single operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What other then arrays *should* collections be?

More importnatly, what other then arrays **could** collections be?

In use collection boils down to "arrays - and stuff we wrap around arrays, for ease of use.":

- The pure thing (arrays), wich do offer some conveniences like bounds checks in C#/.NET
- Self growing arrays (Lists)
- Two synchronized arrays that allow the mapping of any any input to any element (Dictionaries key/value pair)
- Three synchornized array: Key, Value and a Hashvalue to quickly identify not-matching keys (HastTable).

Below the hood - regardless of how hard .NET makes it to use pointers - it all boils down to some code doing C/C++ style pointer arythmethic to get the next element.

Edit 1: As I learned in another place, .NET Dictionaries are actually implemented as HashLists. The HashList class is just the pre-generics version. Object has a GetHashCode function with sensible default behavior wich can be used, but also fully overwritten.

Fragmentation wise the "best" would be a array of references. It can be as small as the reference width (a Pointer or slightly bigger) and the GC can move around the instances to defragment memory. Of course then you get the slight overhead of accessing references rather the just counting/mathing up a pointer, so as usualy it is a memory vs speed tradeoff. However this might go into [Speed Rant Territory of detail](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Edit 2: As Markus Appel pointed out in the comments, there is something even better for fragmentation avoidance: [Linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). Even that single array of references - if you just make it big enough - will take quite some memory in one indivisible chunk. So it might run into object size limits or array indexer limits. A linked list will do neither. But as a result the performance is around a disk that was never defragmented.

Generics is just a convience to have typesafety in collections/other places. It avoids you having to use the dreaded Object as type, wich ruins all compile-time typesafety. Afaik they add nothing else to this situation. `List<string>` works the same as a `StringList` would.

Comment: There is another way to represent collections, which do not require an array: Linked lists.

Comment: @MarkusAppel which would be a lot more expensive when you count the traversal and node allocation cost. Inserting 100K items requires 100K nodes that have to be GCd. With an array the cost may be 0 - just store a value in the next empty location in the buffer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The performance is a valid point. Still, many programming lanugages use linked lists as their default collection model due to their flexibility.

Comment: @MarkusAppel I had not considered linekd lists. Yes, for fragmentation this has to be even *better* then a array of references. There is no object bigger then 1 instance + 2 references. Even the large object that is the array does not appear. And it does get you around stuff like array/object size limits. But performance wise it boils down to "how can we take arrays and remove their entire speed advantage?" Those languages that use linked lists by default are propably not too performance orientend.

Comment: @MarkusAppel Added your remark. And I realized: If you know you only work with linked lists, you can optimize your GC to defragment them like you would a HDD. it would at least help with stuff like prefetching and other "let us get a block at once" cases.

Comment: @Christopher No, those languages usually can't be used for writing a physics engine, that's true, but some operations can actually be really efficient, especially when thinking about functional data structures like binary trees.

Answer (score 1):

Array access is faster as it is a linear storage. If Arrays can solve a problem well enough they are a better storage for traversal rather than always identifying where the next object is stored. For Large data structures this performance benefit will also be amplified.

Comment: I hope, for reference type it just stores the references in linear fashion not the instance itself. yes it could give a slighter advantage during traversal but i am wondering with LOH fragmentation in play would it still be effective?

Comment: @Ravi for value types, is stores the values themselves

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes. And there could be possible fragmentation with reference types as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays can cause fragmentation if used carelessly. In the general case though, the performance gains outweigh the cost.

When the buffer runs out, the collection allocates a new one with double the size. If the code inserts a lot of items *without* specifying a capacity, this results in log2(N) reallocations. If the code *does* specify a capacity though, even a *very* rough approximation, there may be no fragmentation issues at all.

Removal is another expensive case as the collection will have to move the items after the deleted item(s) to the left.

In general though, array storage offers far better performance than other storage structures though, both for reading,  inserting *and* allocating memory. Deletions are rare in most cases.

For example, inserting N items in a linked list requires allocating N objects to hold that value and storing N pointers. That cost will be paid for every insertion, while the GC will have a lot more objects to track and collect. Inserting 100K items in a linked list would allocate 100K node objects that would need tracking.

With an array there won't be any allocations unless the buffer runs out. In the majority of cases insertion means simply writing to a buffer location and updating a count. When the buffer runs out there will be a single reallocation and an (expensive) copy operation. For 100K items, that's 17 allocations. In most cases, that's an acceptable cost.

To reduce or even get rid of allocations, the code can specify a capacity that's used as the initial buffer size. Specifying even a *very* rough estimate can reduce allocations a lot. Specifying 1024 as the initial capacity for 100K items would reduce reallocations to 7.